# Size of Black dots and Labels position

Tags: labels, tkz-euclide

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1 in,bottom=1 in,left=0.7 in,right=0.7 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide,xcolor,graphicx}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\large

    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}

    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 9/0/B, 3/0/P, 6/0/Q}

    \draw[thick](A)--(B);

    \tkzDrawPoints[color=black](A,B,P,Q)
    \tkzDefPoint[label=below:{$A(x_1,y_1)$}](0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint[label=below:{$B(x_2,y_2)$}](3,0){B}
    \tkzDefPoint[label=below:{$P(x_3,y_3)$}](6,0){P}
    \tkzDefPoint[label=below:{$Q(x_4,y_4)$}](9,0){Q}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

I have two following questions.

Question : 1 How can i increase the size of black dots?

Question : 2 I want to lable cooedinates (x1 , y1) exactly below the name A instead of A(x1 , y1). I need same for rest coordinates.

Comment: To make the dots bigger you can add to `\tkzDrawPoints` the `size=val` option, where `val` is a multiplier of `\pgflinewidth` according to the [`tkz-euclide` Manual](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-euclide/doc/tkz-euclide-screen.pdf). To make the Labels above youl could use `\tkzLabelPoints[above](A,B,P,Q)`

Comment: You have some conflicting options, `letterpaper` in the class options, and `a4paper` for `geometry`.

Comment: yes you are right......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To increase the of the dots, just add `size=<length>` to the `\tkzDrawPoints` options. If you need to move the labels down, you can add `[label distance=<length>]` after `\begin{tikzpicture}`. This will affect any other labels in there as well, alternatively place the `\tkzDefPoint`s in a `scope` environment and add the option to that, or add `label distance` to each label.

To get the a line break in  a label, you need to set `align` (or `text width`) for the label, e.g. with

```
\tkzDefPoint[label={[align=center]below:$A$\\$(x_1,y_1)$}](0,0){A}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\large

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[label distance=5pt]

\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 9/0/B, 3/0/P, 6/0/Q}

\draw[thick](A)--(B);

\tkzDrawPoints[color=black,size=1cm](A,B,P,Q)
\tkzDefPoint[label={[align=center]below:$A$\\$(x_1,y_1)$}](0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint[label={[align=center]below:$B$\\$(x_2,y_2)$}](3,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint[label={[align=center]below:$P$\\$(x_3,y_3)$}](6,0){P}
\tkzDefPoint[label={[align=center]below:$Q$\\$(x_4,y_4)$}](9,0){Q}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for dragging my attention to the mistake. and big thanks for solution